# Flutter: how to calculate total working hours by using time in and time out

Tags: flutter, time, calculation

I am creating an app where user can time in and time out, i want to add the functionality of calculating the total working hours. for example if time in value is 10:30 and time out value is 12:30 then total working hours should be 2.

please help how i can do this.

**Update:**

```
  final DateTime checkInTime = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 9, minutes: 10));
  final DateTime checkOutTime = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 5, minutes: 10));
  
  final hours = checkOutTime.difference(checkInTime).inHours;
  final minutes= checkOutTime.difference(checkInTime).inMinutes;
  final totalWorkingHours = '$hours.${(minutes - (hours*60))} hrs';
  print("hours  "+totalWorkingHours);  //output 4.0 hrs
```

it gives me 4 workinghours but it should have 6:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with simple math i.e

time out - time in = total working hours

Let's break down how to solve this in flutter

1. First save the timestamp when user is `In` in DateTime i.e DateTime.now()
2. Repeat step 1 for the `Out`
3. Now if both are not null calculate the difference

code will look like

```
DateTime inTime = populateYourInTimeHere();
DateTime outTime =  poupulateYourOutTimeHere();

Duration workingHours = outTime.difference(inTime);// main part you need to know

format(Duration d) => d.toString().split('.').first.padLeft(8, "0");



 
The total working hour is format(workingHours)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this

```
void main() {
  final DateTime checkInTime = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 3));
  final DateTime checkOutTime = DateTime.now();
  
  final totalWorkingHours = checkOutTime.difference(checkInTime).inHours;
  print(totalWorkingHours);
}
```

Output will be 3

The above code only handle the hours, but if you want to handle both hrs and minutes then use the below code

```
void main() {
  final DateTime checkInTime = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 3, minutes: 30));
  final DateTime checkOutTime = DateTime.now();
  
  final hours = checkOutTime.difference(checkInTime).inHours;
  final minutes= checkOutTime.difference(checkInTime).inMinutes;
  final totalWorkingHours = '$hours.${(minutes - (hours*60))} hrs';
  print(totalWorkingHours);
}
```

Output will be 3.30 hrs

Comment: hey, there? can u please the update code, i am using ur code but it gives me wrong answer of totalworkinghours. please check the updated code above.

Comment: @TimeToCode I have seen your code, it should be 4 right, 
CheckInTime: 2021-07-29 05:48:37.737
CheckOutTime: 2021-07-29 09:48:37.737
Difference: hours 4.0 hrs

Please correct me if I'm wrong, May I know what is your use case.

Comment: i want when user timein at 9am and timeout at 5pm so the total difference in working hour is 8, i did that by using 24hour format time. thankyou for ur reply!

Comment: @TimeToCode Have you got your answer?

Comment: @ Mohan Sai Manthri yes i got it!